# Computing hessian with pydrake autodiff

Tags: drake

One of Drake's selling points is the easy availability of gradients via AutoDiff, but I'm struggling to see how to easily compute second-order derivatives in pydrake.

Given a function f(x), I know of two ways to compute the Jacobian. The first way uses the `forwarddiff.jacobian` helper function, e.g.:

```
def f(x):
    return x.T@x

x = np.array([1,2,3])
fx = jacobian(f,x)     # = [2,4,6]
```

The second way uses the `autodiffutils` bindings more directly:

```
x = InitializeAutoDiff([1,2,3])
y = f(x)
fx = ExtractGradient(y)   # = [2,4,6]
```

Are there similar ways to get the Hessian? Nested calls to the `jacobian` helper function don't work, since the second argument can't be an `AutoDiffXd` type. But perhaps there is some way more analogous to the second method above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current recommended answer is to use `symbolic::Expression` instead of `AutoDiffXd` when you need more than one derivative.  While all of our C++ code should work if it was compiled with `AutoDiffX<AutoDiffXd>` to provide second derivatives, we currently don't build those as one of our default scalar types in `libdrake.so`.

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid this might be the answer. The function in my use case is quite complicated (forward dynamics of a `MultibodyPlant`), so `symbolic::Expression` isn't really practical. But it's good to know that second derivatives are at least possible in C++.

Comment: Just to make sure you know, you can get farther with `symbolic::Expression` in `MultibodyPlant` using `CalcImplicitTimeDerivativesResidual`: https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#aba4403ae1b096297581cb24957ede9aa

It's the `inv(M(q))` that normally kills symbolic, which can be avoided in the implicit form.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that has become available more recently could be to take the symbolic expressions from Drake and use them in a different framework like pytorch: See https://github.com/DAIRLab/drake-pytorch , for instance.  We also have some c++ [codegen (from symbolic)](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1symbolic_1_1_code_gen_visitor.html#a7b55a258854d77cb53a4bac286b1a8e7) capability directly in Drake.